# Angular2 + Webpack DefinePlugin not working?

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack

I tried to run the Angular2 app from the tutorial on the angular.io website

[Angular2 with Webpack Tutorial on angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html)

Installation worked well (with a few hiccups, it's **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**) but I got to the point where the *npm start* task works, the server works, and even the app works in the browser, so far so good. **But**

Everytime I run *npm start*, I get the following 2 errors in the terminal, AND in the browser console:

```
ERROR in ./src/polyfills.ts
(4,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'process'.

ERROR in ./src/main.ts
(7,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'process'.
```

If you look at the tutorial, it is explained how to create the webpack configs, there is a webpack.common.js, a webpack.prod.js and a webpack.dev.js. In the **webpack.prod.js**, a var is created with this code:

```
const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.ENV = 'production';
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
        'ENV': JSON.stringify(ENV)
    }
})
```

In **main.ts** and in **polyfills.ts** the var is referenced by this:

```
if (process.env.ENV === 'production') {
    enableProdMode();
}
```

but it seems, that [Typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) does not know how to inject these variables, created with **webpack.DefinePlugin** into the compiled Javascript (that's what I'm thinking, I maybe wrong)

If anyone ran into the same problem, or anyone can help me with this, I would be very thankful! (All the code is from the tutorial, so anyone who tried the tutorial may have run into the same problem, I guess?!)

Thank You!

Answer (score 14):

I was having the same issue here (doing the same tutorial). To solve this I created a file named typings.d.ts on the same folder where typings.json is (this file will be included by default by the compiler) and added the following declaration to it:

```
declare var process: any;
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: will give u a party for this

Comment: add `@types/node` to your `devDependencies`, and it will take care of this for you